# update records of two columns by name in txt file java

Tags: java, crud, txt

I have txt file with employees
It contains name, date, post, salary:

```
Asher 2022/04/05 HR-Manager 24000
```

I've changed my code, this one works fine (maybe would be helpfull for someone):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("•\tWrite name of employee to change salary and post");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("•\tNew post:");
        String post = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("•\tNew salary:");
        String salary = sc.nextLine();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldFileName));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmpFileName));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] arr =line.split(" ");
                if (line.contains(name))
                    line = line.replace(arr[2], post);
                bw.write(line+"\n");
            }
```

Comment: The columns in one line of the text file are always separated by spaces? If yes, you can use regex to replace. the position 3 by or text for example.

Comment: yes, but how can i do this? @pringi

Comment: @pringi i've got it, I will edit code to one that works

Comment: You should not change the original question. You can answer your own question.

Comment: @pringi i've got it